# iPhone/iOS How to load a lot of image in many folder and show in a table view?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, directory

I got annoying question...

What if I have many image , and I want load it in to a table view

And show the file name as cell's text , and the preview image is also show in the cell.

When I select the cell , it will push to next view , show the big size image.

That's it .

I don't know how to load many folder to an array?

/*********** EDIT ***********/
This is the folder I set many images inside
[image]

You can see that's only one root folder ...

And this is my code to load the image inside

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Image"ofType:@""];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum;
direnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath: filePath];
imageFolder = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSString *filename in direnum){
    if([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"]){
        [imageFolder addObject:filename];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Files in the folder %@",imageFolder);
```

I got result like this :

```
 Files in the folder (
"macro1.png",
"macro10.png",
"macro11.png",
"macro12.png",
"macro13.png",
"macro14.png",
"macro15.png",
"macro16.png",
"macro17.png",
"macro18.png",
"macro19.png",
"macro2.png",
"macro20.png",
"macro21.png",
"macro22.png",
"macro23.png",
"macro24.png",
"macro25.png",
"macro26.png",
"macro27.png",
"macro4.png",
"macro5.png",
"macro6.png",
"macro7.png",
"macro8.png",
"macro9.png"
```

)

But what if I change the root folder like this 
[image]

How to read the image files in the subfolders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The App won't have issues finding files inside the bundle. The structure of your app development folders is irrelevant to the end product, for the most part. If you are storing the images in the apps bundle, the system can find it.

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png"]];
```

When I've had to do this as a quicky solution, I created an NSDictionary entry for each photo and stored that inside of an array in userPrefs. I programmatically created thumbnails for each image to utilize in the cell.imageView.image property, and then used an NSDictionary with @"description", @"imageName", and @"imageNameThumbnail" as the keys. You could do the same thing with an NSArray and just call the objectAtIndex, but I prefer the plain text friendliness of dictionaries.

You can try testing the path information that is being returned. Here are a couple of lines to try:

```
NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png"];
NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"folderName"];
NSLog(@"Path 1: %@",path1);
NSLog(@"Path 2: %@",path2);
```

See what the output for these lines is, or if they return nothing.

**Documents Directory as filePath**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then, enumerate the documentsDirectoryPath, and it should read subfolders recursively.

Comment: Thanks,this is what I do , but I got empty data ....
I add a folder named "Image",and add many png in the folder.
Than I try to give a file path
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Image"ofType:@""];
But I'm not sure which type I need to set ?

Comment: And I got warning with your code 
warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct NSString *', expected 'struct UIImage *'
What's that mean ???

Comment: I updated my answer. I had left out the UIImage init statement which would cause the UIImage to acquire the wrong data type. Go ahead and update to the code above, and take a look at the testing code I posted.

Comment: I got this result 
Path 2: /Users/macminiserver/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/5A5B3DF9-5EF5-4B41-B684-EDC84C171253/LoadFolder.app/Image/Image1
Can I get the folder name ???
Here is my folder path like :
RootFolder ->Folder1,Folder2,Folder3...
And The image is in the Folder1,2,3...
So My table view will has two layer , first is list all the folders name,Second list all the image in the folder.

Comment: I assume Path1 was blank. If the image was named "Image1", then the Path2 statement returned your image path correctly. My guess is that these will be subfolders of the Documents directory. You could use the contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: command to list out the files in the documents directory, and then from there, iterate the array it returns, checking against isDirectory and writing directories to another separate array. You could then use that list to pull file data. Alternately if the directories will always be the same, you could store the names in their own array in preferences.

Comment: In your pathForResource, you are using the actual image name, correct? Not @"Image"? The image Name will need to be set somewhere else in a variable and then called. Also, in regards to your additional code, NSDirectoryEnumerator is automagically recursive, so you don't need to do anything there. The issue then become that you don't want to use the pathForResource: to pull the filePath. Assuming they are subdirectories of the documentsDirectory, you would use the code I added to my original response above.

Answer (score 0):

If it is local data you are using, you probably want to put the data in a .plist file. You would just be putting the names of the files in there, and then load the plist into an NSDictionary which you will only have one key for called "images" or something like that. You can then load all the objects under the "images" key into an array and use that array to populate your table.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: yes , it is local data.and how to add a image into plist ?
Root > Array >Item 0 >Type Data >Value ???

Comment: You just want to add an NSString for each image which is the name of the image - eg - image123.png. Then when you read it out of the array to display it, you will call [UIImage imageNamed:image]; where "image" is an NSString holding the name of your image.

Comment: Property lists can only hold NSString,NSArray,NSDictionary,NSData,NSDate,NSNumber or boolean values.

Comment: The image is too much ...about 5000 pics...No other way to give a file names ?