# Memory problems using arc

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, uiviewanimation

i'm new on Objective-C programming and i'm having the typical memory problems. I must do an app based on navigation controller and when passing few views (using push view controller), load an animation of 100 images. In the simulator works well, but on the phone not... I open up different animations and then it closes. I'm using arc to avoid that, but it seems not to be working. I've also tried to disable arc and release the UIImageView manually but it crashes even quickly. Here's an example of one of that views:

```
    //.h
@interface Gegant_nou : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageViewGegant; 
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* ImageViewGegant;

//.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIBarButtonItem *rigthButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Detalls" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(canviarDetalls)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rigthButton;
    [rigthButton release];


    ImageViewGegant.animationImages =@
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"0001.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"0002.png"],
        . load all the images
        .
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"0099.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"0100.png"]];

    ImageViewGegant.animationDuration = 4;
    ImageViewGegant.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [ImageViewGegant startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:ImageViewGegant];

    self.title = @"Gegant nou";

    [ImageViewGegant release];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.

}

- (void)viewDidUnload{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [ImageViewGegant release];
}
```

Any idea of why happens? Thank you for helping me!

Comment: 1. which line does it throw the exception? 2. the `-viewDidUnload` is deprecated under iOS6 you should avoid to use it (it will be never called). 3. why don't you init your image array using loop?

Comment: There is some debate on memory use from using ImageNamed to load vs initwtihcontentsoffile. See this post for some good info on the other option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566827/iphone-ios-how-to-load-a-lot-of-image-in-many-folder-and-show-in-a-table-view

Comment: @holex what should I use instead of viewDidUnload? dealloc?

Comment: @user1600400, according to the documentation you should use the `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` method for releasing everything what you won't need any more.

Comment: ok @holex, i'll do it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! What was happening was that I was using UIImageNamed to load the animation, and although I was using ARC, UIImageNamed loads the image but don't releases it, so it loads all the frames and fills the memory very quickly. Now I don't have that memory problems. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to assist you if you provided some crashlog or stacktrace to provide more information about where the problem lies.

Are you totally sure the problem is memory related at all? Since you are using ARC it is pretty unlikely unless you have parts of your codebase where you don't use ARC or if you use c libraries like CoreGraphics etc, where you still need to retain/release even if you use ARC.

If you do have memory problems with say overrelease and you get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash, you can try to enable zombies in your app by Product -> Edit scheme.. -> Diagnostics and then "Enable Zombie objects". This will hopefully provide more information of the objects that are causing the problem.

On a completely different topic, I would strongly advice you to write all instance variables with camelcase. It is confusing to read, most developers will assume "ImageViewGegant" is the name of a class.

Comment: I have a memory problem, as you say I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS [view the capture here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2720540/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202012-09-29%20a%20les%2021.14.21.png). I'm using coregraphics library. Thanks for all.